# Не работает margin без положительного padding

Tags: html, css

Вот есть такой сильно не замысловатый код, но, обратите внимание на класс padding. У него padding-top стоит 1px и тогда класс .tarif опускается вниз в соответствии с выставленным в нём margin (т.е. на 640px), но если в классе padding поставить padding-top равный 0 то уезжает вниз вся связка, в том числе и contact_rko. Почему так происходит и как это исправить т.е. что бы можно было не ставить padding у класса padding и при этом использовать margin у .tarif?

> CSS

```
    .wrap{
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    .contact_rko{
        background-color: #e6eaed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 480px;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .tarif{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 888px;
        height: 80px;
        background-color: #0071c7;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #00477e;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 640px 0 0 0;
    }
.padding{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px 0 0 0;
}

    .tarif_h{
        font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
        font-size: 36px;
        padding: 20px 0 0 0;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        display: block;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

> HTML

```
<div class="contact_rko">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="padding">
                    <div class="tarif">
                        <span class="tarif_h">тарифы</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Происходит так называемое схлопывание марджина. И это довольно странный частный случай сего явления. Марджин по прежнему действует, но сдвигает не элемент, а его родителя. Это "правильное" поведение, по спецификации.

Как вариант могу вам посоветовать добавить к родителю `overflow: auto`

Либо делать подобные отступы через `padding-top` родителя

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins